# Probleme about pagination

Tags: java, spring, pagination

I need your help im a begineer in spring boot,so i have a probleme for pagination in spring boot

> : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'maBanqueApplication': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'operationRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'operationRepository': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for
>   method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page
>   com.example.demo.dao.OperationRepository.findBylistOperation(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!

Repository:

```
public interface OperationRepository 
extends JpaRepository<Operation, Long> {

    @Query("select o from operation where o.compte.codeCompte=:x order by o.dateOpeartion desc")


    public Page<Operation> findBylistOperation(@Param("x" )String codeCpte,Pageable pageable);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in JPA query:

```
@Query("select o from Operation o where o.compte.codeCompte = :x order by o.dateOpeartion desc")
```

You forgot to add alias (`o`) for `Operation`.